# SQL Grouping by data

Tags: sql

Good Day,

I have a sql query that returns the following data:

```
EmployeeID...Employee
555..........John Doe
666..........Jane Doe
777..........Bob Smith
888..........Jane Smith
999..........Fred Jones
000..........Freda Jones
```

and I want my query to group by items of three:

```
Item.........EmployeeId........Employee
1............555...............John Doe
1............666...............Jane Doe
1............777...............Bob Smith
2............888...............Jane Smith
2............999...............Fred Jones
2............000...............Freda Jones
```

In other words, for every record that has more than 3 records, I want to increment Item by one every three records..

I am sure that I can use some sort of row insert into a table and keep track of the number of rows inserted into a table.  But I'm trying to see if I can pull this off in SQL itself.

Is this possible?

TIA,

coson

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  There may be different solutions depending on whether you're using SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL etc...

Comment: Group by employeeId andemployee and divide count by 3?

Comment: You will also need some ordering criteria that you're missing in your question

Comment: Good points.  I wrote this late at night when my brain capacity was approaching 20% and falling.  It is for SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database's SQL variety supports ranking functions, you could try something like this:

```
SELECT
  FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmployeeID) + 2) / 3) AS Item,
  EmployeeID,
  Employee
FROM Employees
ORDER BY EmployeeID
```

Some database systems automatically perform integral division when both operands are integers, others support a dedicated operator (like `DIV`) for integral division instead of `/`. In both mentioned cases `FLOOR()` would be unnecessary, of course.

Comment: (Very) minor nitpick: the official (ANSI standard) name for those functions is "windowing function" (not ranking function)

Comment: Very well, thanks for that notice, I actually didn't know that. I thought *windowing functions* was a broader term, though, one that included *windowing aggregate functions* as well. Maybe there's a specific official term that stands for *ranking functions*? You know, like `ROW_NUMBER()`, `RANK()` etc.

Comment: Good point ;) The standard says: "*A window function is: ... a rank function, a distribution function, the row number function, a window aggregate function ...*"

Comment: Ha, ***the** row number function*! I wonder why they decided to set it apart like that, but thanks anyway. For now, I'll leave this answer as it is, but I must endeavour to be more specific in the future when referring to windowing functions in my posts. Thanks again for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Well, this should work in most DBMS:

```
select floor((count(*) + 2) / 3) item, t1.employeeId, t1.employee
from t t1
join t t2 on t1.employeeId >= t2.employeeId
group by t1.employeeId, t1.employee 
order by t1.employeeId
```

You can play with the fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/40c39/1).